# How to remove both duplicates from file based on the first 2 columns

Tags: text-processing, sort

I need to remove both duplicates from file `test.txt` based on first 2 columns:

```
tom,22,777
tom,22,888
tom,18,54
ray,44,43843
```

expected result:

```
tom,18,54
ray,44,43843
```

I tried using `cat test.txt | sort -u t, k1,1 k2,2` but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk`: process the file twice, once to count the occurrences of 1st and 2nd fields and then again to print lines if count is 1:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{seen[$1,$2]++;next};seen[$1,$2]==1' infile infile
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, assuming GNU `grep(1)` (for `fgrep -f -`), and assuming fields in your input consist only of alphanumeric characters:

```
cut -d , -f 1,2 file.csv | sort | uniq -d | fgrep -vwf - file.csv
```

Comment: cut -d , -f 1,2 file.csv | sort | uniq -u | fgrep -vwf - file.csv is removing the duplicats but i am getting the result without the third field @ Sato Katsura

Comment: @WAEL Then you aren't using GNU `grep(1)`.  Or you you have some alias messing with results.

Comment: @ Sato when i past the same query you provided  cut -d , -f 1,2 test.txt | sort | uniq -d | fgrep -vwf - test.txt  i will get error  "fgrep: 0652-033 Cannot open-."

Comment: @WAEL Then you aren't using GNU `grep(1)`.

Comment: @ Sato how can I check whether i am using GNU grep(1) thanks for your support

Comment: @WAEL `grep --version`, look for "GNU grep".

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 cat file.txt | grep -v  "`cut -d , -f 1,2 file.txt | uniq -d`"
```

Comment: Dear Prince i am getting "grep: 0652-226 Maximum line length of 8192 exceeded." once the file is getting bigger how can i resolve this issue